# Best score com playerprefs unity-android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Ola.
Fiz um sistema de best score normal no unity (quando score>playerprefs, vai setar o texto do textmesh).
No computador deu certo, só que quando passo pro Android o bestscore fica 0
Alguem saberia o que é iss

Comment: Olá Ostruque10, bem vindo ao SOPT. Você já fez algum teste para se certificar que o pedaço de código em que a mudança do *score* ocorre é realmente executado no Android (por exemplo, logando ou exibindo na tela um "passei aqui")? Aliás, seria importante colocar na pergunta o pedaço de código em que essa alteração é efetuada, senão fica muito difícil alguém conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: Foi mal pela demora, eu tinha colocado a variavel na Playerprefs.getInt agora ja está publicado se puder dar uma olhada https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Deploy.Racintwings

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, veja se não está relacionado ao caminho do playerprefs no Android, pois é diferente do PC.

No Android eles são armazenados na memória interna do telefone em `/data/data/appname/shared_prefs/appname.xml`.

Onde appname é o identificador de pacote completo por exemplo `com.mycomany.example`.
Bons estudos!